# Check boxes: Allow for only one check box to be click at a time

Tags: javascript

I am currently working with check boxes and displaying values based on the values chosen. Almost everything is working in exception that i have to check boxes for `method of shipping`. Right now the user can select two ways and this is an issue. Is there a way to only allow one check box to be checked for `method of shipping`? [EXAMPLE](http://webprolearner2346.zxq.net/bike_calculator/)

**JS**

```
<script>
function check_value(currentElement, val, id, type) {
    var el = document.getElementById("imgBox" + id);
    if (val > 0 && val < 4) { //will trigger when [1,2,3]

        if(currentElement.checked)
        {
            el.src = "images/" + type + val + ".jpg";
            el.style.display = "";
        }
        else
        {
            el.src = "";
            el.style.display = "none";
        }

    }
}    
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<h2>Choose method of shipping</h2>
<form name="shipping_list">
    <input type="checkbox" name="shipping1" onclick='check_value(this, 1, "4", "shipping")'/> USPS Ground<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="shipping2" onclick='check_value(this, 2, "4", "shipping")'/> FedEx         
</form>

<img id="imgBox4" src="#" style="display:none">
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use radio buttons instead:

```
<form name="shipping_list">
    <input type="radio" name="shipping" id="shipping1" onclick='check_value(this, 1, "4", "shipping")'/> USPS Ground<br />
    <input type="radio" name="shipping" id="shipping2" onclick='check_value(this, 2, "4", "shipping")'/> FedEx         
</form>
```

The key is the `name` attribute, the value should be same for all the radio buttons that belong to one group.

Answer (score 3):

How about [radio buttons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio_button)?

```
<input type="radio" name="shipping" onclick="check_value(this, 1, '4', 'shipping');">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() { 
  $('input[type="checkbox"]').bind('click',function() {
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').not(this).prop("checked", false);
  });
});
```